# Solving equation of static equilibrium

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, physics

I know that:
$$\frac{T_2}{T_1} = e^{\mu_s \pi}$$
$$\tau = (T_2-T_I)R$$

why:

$$T_1 = \frac{\tau}{R}*\frac{1}{e^{\mu_s \pi}-1}$$

I was trying to put t_2 from the second eq to the first then solve for t_1 but this didnt work:

do I have enought data or I am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $$T_2=T_1 e^{μ_s π}$$
so substituting that to the second equation gives you:
$$τ=(T_2-T_1)R=(T_1 e^{μ_s π}-T_1)R=(e^{μ_s π}-1)T_1R$$
Dividing by $(e^{μ_s π}-1)R$ yields: $$T_1=\frac{τ}{R}*\frac{1}{(e^{μ_s π}-1)}$$
as wanted.